# Mapping memory to a CLSID structure

Tags: types, windbg

An MSI package is loading the .NET 4 runtime into my process at the following callstack:

```
0:000> kb
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
...
05 0020bc08 753db8a4 004e639c 0020bc48 0020bc34 ntdll!LdrLoadDll+0x92
...
08 0020be88 73d452dd 0020bee0 71c8f77e 0020bed8 fusion!InitializeVM+0x2a
09 0020be90 71c8f77e 0020bed8 0020cf38 00000001 fusion!CreateAssemblyNameObject+0x8
0a 0020bee0 71c133c5 0020cf36 0020d148 0020cec4 msi!GetFusionPath+0x8f
...
11 0020dc20 6e961d98 04454a80 0020dd04 0020dd00 msi!MsiProvideComponentFromDescriptorW+0x6b
...
13 0020dcd4 755bea87 04454a80 0020dd04 0020dd00 advapi32!CommandLineFromMsiDescriptor+0x1d5
...
1f 0020e3b8 5e4d8f0e 004e489c 00000015 00000000 ole32!CoGetClassObject+0x20
...
24 0020e5dc 045b1652 0199ce38 0199cb08 0199c9f4 mscorwks!JIT_New+0xa6
```

The first parameter to [CoGetClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is of type REFCLSID, which is a pointer to a class ID. I now want to dump the memory into the CLSID structure, but I cannot find it. I tried `dt REFCLSID`, `dt CLSID`, `dt LPCLSID` and `dt _CLSID` and googled for it.

How do I dump a class ID in WinDbg to find out which object loads the .NET 4 runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datatype is [_GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Using it with the first parameter of CoGetClassObject even prints it nicely.

```
0:000> dt _GUID 004e489c
ntdll!_GUID
 {8a385f1a-1622-4169-9010-0ad2d35f51c0}
   +0x000 Data1            : 0x8a385f1a
   +0x004 Data2            : 0x1622
   +0x006 Data3            : 0x4169
   +0x008 Data4            : [8]  "???"
```

Look up the value in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\...\InProcServer32` to find the DLL. From the DLL information you might find the vendor.